# Is there a way to find a string in a HTML file and return its XPath?

Tags: beautifulsoup, scrapy, lxml, python-3.7

I'm trying to do reverse engineering in a scraper to generate a model to extract data.

So, I know the title of a page and I want to look for it inside an HTML code and then return the XPath or CSS Selector to this location.

I'm using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org) in my project, but, for this reverse engineering, I thought maybe [Beautiful Soup 4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#) combined with lxml parser could help me too. I just haven't found any docs about it.

Does anyone know if there is a way to do this?

Comment: yes.. you can do the long winded walk down the DOM building the xpath til you hit your desired element. But the question as is is too broad/off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're actually using lxml, you could use [`getpath()`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#getpath)...

```py
from lxml import etree

xml = """
<doc>
    <one>
        <two>
            <test>foo</test>
        </two>
        <two>
            <test>bar</test>
        </two>
    </one>
</doc>
"""

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)

for match in tree.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'bar')]"):
    print(etree.ElementTree(tree).getpath(match))
```

This prints:

```xml
/doc/one/two[2]/test
```

Comment: Thanks, Daniel! It actually worked exactly as I needed!